# Access forbidden facebook login

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, authentication

I have a problem. I am currently working on a php-project and I implemented a facebook-login system. I redirected my users to a file on my local host. However, When I try to login i get this error:

You don't have permission to access /rent-a-Student/codeigniter/application/views/users/User_view.php on this server.

In the console I see:

GET http://localhost/rent-a-Student/codeigniter/application/views/users/User_vi…WK9-EQOdn475FhwznNhICtrlSMqO6t3c7qp&state=3beb2184e0ca8bf17289be263cc83ddf 403 (Forbidden)

this is my login_fb file:

```
<?php
// start session
session_start();

// loading facebook srcfiles
require_once 'autoload.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;

// initialise app, helper and get session
$app_id = '480209908792754';
$app_secret = '86e572d72f8720363b0c01552953e064';
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id, $app_secret);

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://localhost/rent-a-Student/codeigniter/application/views/users/User_view.php');
$session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();

// if session exists ,get user info
if(isset($session)) {
    $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
    $response = $request->execute();
    $graph = $response->getGraphObject();

    $_SESSION['id']= $graph->getProperty('id');
    $_SESSION['name']= $graph->getProperty('name');
    $_SESSION['email']= $graph->getProperty('email');

    header("Location: ../views/users/User_view.php"); 
} else {
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
    header("Location: ".$loginUrl);
}
```

On the facebook developer site, I linked everything correct (I think).
I hope you guys can help me with this.

Comment: instead of localhost you use site name and try!!

Comment: My site is not on the internet yet, if that is what you mean :)

Comment: This seems to have little (to nothing) to do with Facebook, but is just a problem with your codeigniter routing.

Answer (score 0):

Never see the error message. But I tested the code and saw that facebook redirect to the correct url (although not exist in my computer), so the problem should be caused by the codeigniter url redirect mechanism.